# pagination with join and array in cakephp

Tags: cakephp, pagination

In cakephp I used a 'find all' to do a complex and this works fine as below. My issue is I am trying to convert this to a set  paginated results and I keep getting offset warning Illegal offset type [CORE\Cake\Model\Model.php, line 2936.
I am sure the issue is simple but is there a way to to do this with the $option arrays I have for the search . I didnt see an example in the docs for the paginate results with an array set for the options

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/pagination.html

```
   $this->Lesson->recursive = -1;


        $options['joins'] = array(
            array('table' => 'lessons_students',
                'alias' => 'LessonsStudent',
                'type' => 'LEFT',
                'conditions' => array(
                'Lesson.id = LessonsStudent.lesson_id',
                 )
                 ),

           array('table' => 'students',
                'alias' => 'Student',
                'type' => 'LEFT',
                'conditions' => array(
                'LessonsStudent.student_id=Student.id',
                 )
                 ),
           array('table' => 'subjects',
                        'alias' => 'Subject',
                        'type' => 'LEFT',
                        'conditions' => array(
                        'Lesson.subject_id=Subject.id',
                 )
                 ),
           array(
            'table' => 'tutors',
            'alias' => 'Tutor',
            'type' => 'LEFT',
            'conditions' => array(
            'Lesson.tutor_id = Tutor.id'
        )
        )  ,
          array('table' => 'tutoring_types',
                        'alias' => 'TutoringType',
                        'type' => 'LEFT',
                        'conditions' => array(
                        'Lesson.tutoring_type_id=TutoringType.id',
                 )
                 )
            );

          $options['fields'] = array('Student.last_name','Student.first_name','Student.id',
                    'Lesson.lesson_date', 'Lesson.start_time', 'Lesson.end_time', 'Lesson.id','Lesson.schedule_rec','Lesson.schedule_monthly','Lesson.schedule_yearly',
              'Lesson.cancelled_by', 'Lesson.makeup_lesson', 'Lesson.tutoring_type_id', 'Lesson.forefit',
                    'LessonsStudent.*',
                    'Tutor.last_name', 'Tutor.first_name','Tutor.id',
                    'Subject.name','Subject.id',
                    'TutoringType.*');



             $options['conditions'] = array('Lesson.lesson_inactive' => 0,'Lesson.makeup_lesson' => 0,'Lesson.forefit' => 0,
                         'Lesson.lesson_date >= ' => $startdate,  'Lesson.lesson_date <= ' => $enddate,
                      'AND' =>array(
                      array('OR' => array(
                                   array('Student.first_name LIKE'  => '%' . $searchFirstName  . '%'),
                                   array('Tutor.first_name LIKE'  => '%' . $searchFirstName  . '%'),
                                   array('Student.guardian_first_name LIKE'  => '%' . $searchFirstName  . '%'),
                        ),
                      array('OR' => array(
                                   array('Student.last_name LIKE'  => '%' . $searchLastName  . '%'),
                                   array('Tutor.last_name LIKE'  => '%' . $searchLastName  . '%'),
                                   array('Student.guardian_last_name LIKE'  => '%' . $searchLastName  . '%'),

                        ) ,
                        array('OR' => array(
                                   array('Student.student_mobile LIKE'  => '%' . $searchmobile  . '%'),
                                   array('Tutor.mobile LIKE'  => '%' . $searchmobile   . '%'),
                                   array('Student.guardian_mobile LIKE'  => '%' . $searchmobile   . '%'),

                        )   

                          ))))

          );

            $options['order'] =array('Lesson.lesson_date','Lesson.start_time');             
         $options['limit'] =150;
          $options['page'] =1;

       //    $lessons= $this->Lesson->find('all', $options ); 

          $options['recursive'] =50;

           $this->Paginator->settings = array($options);

          $lessons= $this->Paginator->paginate('Lesson');
```

Comment: This is complicated join :)

Comment: You have an easier way?

Comment: Is there an answer for pagination?

Comment: What you want to do with $options['recursive'] =50; ?

Comment: sorry that was a mistake as should be -1. Anyway does anyone have a solution?

Comment: I tried sometjing like this and changes   $options['conditions'] to $conditions $this->paginate = array(
   'limit' => 8,
   'conditions' => $conditions  but this came up with error in unknown types in field list?
  );

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The pagination works if you split the options  into there own variables